# Treatement of premarital assets in prenuptial agreement where couple loses assets after marriage

Tags: united-states

One kind of simple prenuptial agreement states that all property acquired prior to the date of the marriage is separate, and will be distributed separately, and all property acquired after the date of the marriage is community, and will be split evenly.

Suppose a couple marries with this kind of boilerplate prenuptial agreement.  Just to put some numbers to it, suppose A has $500,000 in assets and B has $50,000 in assets prior to the date of the marriage.  Further suppose for the sake of simplicity that both hold their assets in cash or cash equivalents such as publicly traded stocks or government bonds, as opposed to real estate or other less liquid assets.

While the couple is married they do a poor job managing their finances and when they file for divorce their assets total $100,000.  How is their remaining asset likely to be split?  I realize the exact split is likely to be conditioned upon the skill of the attorneys involved, and the state the marriage began / ended in, but what would be some reasonable outcomes to expect?  In particular, is the $100,000 likely to be split evenly between the two, or is A likely to receive more of the marital assets, seeing as A contributed much more to the combined asset pool?

Comment: This may depend on the state. If you mingle cash, it becomes much harder to claim that it's prenuptial property.

Comment: Typically a prenup refers to *tangible property* (ie furniture, etc), not cash assets. If the couple is concerned about keeping cash separate, they would have separate accounts and a joint account for shared expenses which would be divided according to state laws, and then something about that in the prenup.